# Selecting a subset of a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DateFrame:

```
 record_id  month  day  year  plot species  sex  wgt 
    33320      33321      1   12  2002     1      DM    M   44
    33321      33322      1   12  2002     1      DO    M   58
    ...          ...      ...  ...  ...    ...    ...   ... ...
```

I want to display columns from year to wgt with values equal 27. 
I have done it on two lines:

```
df_slice =  df[df.year == 27]
df_slice = df_slice.ix[:,'year':]
```

Is there any way to reduce it to one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html):

```
print (df.ix[df.year == 27, 'year':])
```

Sample (value `2001` was added):

```
print (df)
   record     id  month  day  year  plot species sex  wgt
0   33320  33321      1   12  2001     1      DM   M   44
1   33321  33322      1   12  2002     1      DO   M   58

print (df.ix[df.year == 2001, 'year':])
   year  plot species sex  wgt
0  2001     1      DM   M   44
```

Comment: It was very helpful. What about if I want to display years: 2001 and 2002 and the same time. I've tried df.ix[df.year == 2001 & df.year == 2001, 'year':], but it's not the right solution

Comment: You are very close, only add brackets `df.ix[(df.year == 2001) & (df.year == 2001), 'year':],`

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to reduce it to one line?

You can easily combine the 2 lines into 1:

```
df_slice = df[df.year == 27].ix[:,'year':]
```